# What is wrong with the g++ command synatx?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to use Tensorflow shared object in my other C++ code, named as Temp_TF.cc
I am using the following command to create an executable.

```
g++ ../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/example/Temp_TF.so -ltensorflow_cc Temp_TF.cc -o Temp_TF
```

What is wrong with the following command?

I am getting the following error:

```
Temp_TF.cc:3:49: fatal error: tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the problem you're having.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "what is wrong"? You don't show an error or something. We can't help you, if you don't give us information about your actual problem.

Comment: The compiler dictates you the error: `tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h: No such file`. Make sure you are in the right directory and the file actually exists. Note, that it is an absolute path. You may need the `-I` (capital i) to specify your include path

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You shouldn't specify shared objects (.so files) directly as objects to be linked. You specify a library so-name and a path for the compiler to search for libraries (if outside the default search path). For example, to link to the math library (libm), you specify `-lm`, *not* the path to the .so file (the compiler (*actually*, the linker) will find it itself either in the default path or a path you tell it about with `-L`).

Answer (score 2):

I can see you're new to Stack Overflow.

Technically your question does not have enough data for us to provide an answer for sure.

However it looks to me as though you're missing a `-I` (capital i) directive and the compiler does not know where to find the `tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h` path.

From the look of it, you could try:

`g++ -I ../../../bazel-bin ../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/example/Temp_TF.so -ltensorflow_cc Temp_TF.cc -o Temp_TF`

(note the `-I`)

Comment: You might as well put the linker options in a sensible order, while you are at it.